# Accurate scroll position at specific pixel value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a design that I'm trying to "lock" a div to the viewport when it reaches a specific distance within the window by actually adding overflow:hidden to the body. I would prefer to not have to fix it. My question: is there a way where I can get the scroll granular enough where I can trigger it to a specific value? If I scroll too fast, it will just miss the target. Not the worst thing, but requiring slow scroll to engage is a little odd UX.

```
const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
const elementOffset = $("#my-div").offset().top;
const distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

if (distance === 75){
   this.toggleNoScroll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid "missing," you can store the last known result and compare it to the current state.

```
if (lastDistance < 75 && currentDistance >= 75) {
  // Distance is now greater than or equal to 75
} else if (lastDistance >= 75 && currentDistance < 75) {
  // Distance is now less than 75
}

// Store the new value
lastDistance = currentDistance;
```

Also, depending on your use case, `position: sticky` may be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way where I can get the scroll granular enough where I can trigger it to a specific value?

Not really, no. You're at the mercy of how quickly the UI will update the scroll position as well as how fast the user was scrolling.

The alternative is to target a scroll position range, something like this:

```
if (distance >= 75 || distance <= 100) {
   this.toggleNoScroll();
}
```

I'd also suggest you use `position: fixed` for this. If there's a reason you cannot, I'd address that before attempting to find an alternative.